# trouble with Loop in while using button enable/disable as condition JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I started in JavaScript today, I'm trying to make this code that generates passwords while the button is disabled and when is enable the generator stops. The problem is that it only works once even with the button disabled. I tested it using just `console.log('yes')` inside the while and it works fine, but when I add the rest of the code it only works once. What is the reason for this? I started today so I don't really know what to look for to solve my problem

this is the complete code

```js
const pass = document.querySelector('#pass')
const newPassword = document.querySelector('#newPassword')

async function generatePass(){
    document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled = true
    while (document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled == true) {
        await sleep(1)
        console.log('yes')
        newPassword.innerHTML = ''

        if(pass.value === ''){
            alert('Choose the password size!')
            return
        }
        document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled = true
        
        let charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let password = ""

        for(var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < pass.value; ++i){
            password += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n))
        }
        
        let result = document.createTextNode(password)
        return newPassword.appendChild(result)
    }
    async function sleep(seconds) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))
    }
}

function breakgeneratePass(){
    document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled = false
}
```

And this is just with the `console.log('yes')`

```js
const pass = document.querySelector('#pass')
const newPassword = document.querySelector('#newPassword')

async function generatePass(){
    document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled = true
    while (document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled == true) {
        await sleep(1)
        console.log('yes')
    }
    async function sleep(seconds) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))
    }
}

function breakgeneratePass(){
    document.querySelector('#Goal').disabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the `while` loop you do:

```
return newPassword.appendChild(result)
```

This doesn't just break from the loop, it exits the whole `generatePass` function.

You probably just meant:

```
newPassword.appendChild(result)
```

Comment: I fixed this line and it worked perfectly, thank you very much, I didn't know that this return was capable of that, thank you very much